# Opening/Editing Qt Resource File (.rcc)

Tags: qt, resources, rcc

I want to translate a program; but its language files (.qm) are in a .rcc file.

The program is not mine, so I haven't got any .qrc file.

Before asking this question, I have searched this site about this issue; but I don't attain anything.

Is there any way to extract/decompile it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can take my tool [RccExtended](https://github.com/zedxxx/rccextended) - it based on the [official Qt resource compiler](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/tree/dev/src/tools/rcc) with additional function to decompile binary resources.

Usage example:

```
cd \Path\To\MyQtResources\
rcc --reverse
```

Decompiler will unpack all **.rcc** files in the current directory, generate **.qrc** files and **make.bat** file to compile resources back to the binary format.

Comment: Very nice. Thank you so much zed.

Comment: Nice work; thanks for writing this.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a supported way to decompile it as far as I'm aware, but it's a binary file format that can be read and handled. There's a nodejs example of how to read the file and extract PNGs on github: https://github.com/gcochard/png-extractor. It may be possible to extend that method out for the `.qm` files.

However there's other issues with attempting to add more translations to a Qt application without having the code, depending on the language you're attempting to add, how the developer has exposed the other languages etc.

Comment: As I understand it, there is no way to reach qm files which are in the .rcc file. Any way, thanks for your help.